# Total Working Days Calculation in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[Snapshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq77y.png)

I have the table that has some data related to employee start date and end date for specific task

How to calculate "Total Working days" using the above data show in the picture above

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at below posts

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/calculating-the-number-of-business-days-in-a-month

https://community.tableau.com/thread/239362

https://community.tableau.com/thread/126175